How to add multiple markers to flutter map
I'm pretty new (2 days in) to dart(flutter) so bare with me. I am trying to add markers to my open street maps map in my flutter app. I have a csv file with all the points I want to add that looks like this:



place_name
latitude
longitude




data
data
data



I have figured out how to add a single marker - how can I loop through the rows in the csv file to add multiple markers? Here's my current add marker code.
 Future<void> _addSingleMarker() async {
    // Given latitude and longitude
    final latitude = 53.7827922;
    final longitude = -1.5547318;

    markers.clear();
    markers.add(GeoPoint(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude));
    await _addMarkersToMap();
  }

  Future<void> _addMarkersToMap() async {
    for (GeoPoint marker in markers) {
      print("Adding marker at latitude: ${marker.latitude}, longitude: ${marker.longitude}");
      await mapController.addMarker(marker,
          markerIcon: const MarkerIcon(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.location_pin,
              color: Colors.blue,
              size: 48,
            ),
          ));
    }
    print("Markers added to the map");


Does this answer your question? Display multiple markers on Google maps in flutter

No I checked that thank you. I think the main problem is reading the csv - If I've got 500 markers, hard coding each one is a bit of an issue

then your problem is not how to add markers but to read a CSV file

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';

void main() {
runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Flutter Map with Multiple Markers'),
    ),
    body: MapWithMarkers(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MapWithMarkers extends StatelessWidget {
final List<LatLng> markerCoordinates = [
LatLng(53.7827922, -1.5547318), 
LatLng(53.780416, -1.58270),   
];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return FlutterMap(
  options: MapOptions(
    center: LatLng(53.7827922, -1.5547318), // Initial map center
    zoom: 12.0, // Initial zoom level
  ),
  layers: [
    TileLayerOptions(
      urlTemplate: "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
      subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ),
    MarkerLayerOptions(
      markers: _buildMarkers(), 
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  List<Marker> _buildMarkers() {
  List<Marker> markers = [];
   for (int i = 0; i < markerCoordinates.length; i++) {
    markers.add(
    Marker(
      width: 80.0,
      height: 80.0,
      point: markerCoordinates[i], 
      builder: (ctx) => Icon(
        Icons.location_pin, 
        color: Colors.blue,
        size: 48,
         ),
       ),
     );
   }
   return markers;
  }
}


Sorry, to clarify - I don't want to hard code the lat and long, I want to read them from a csv
